# Finding definitions of modules which are parameters with LSP (pyright)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide

Suppose i have the following code in python:

```
module dbm_adapter

def insert_in_database():
   doSomething
```

---

```
module B:
import dbm_adapter

def myfunc(dbm_adapter):
LINE 10    dbm_adapter.insert_in_database()

myfunc(dbm_adapter)
```

When i go to line 10 and i click on insert_in_database() in my IDE with emacs using lsp, the definition of the function is not found. Is it possible to jump to that definition with lsp?

Comment: I don't know but I see a typo: "dbm_adap**a**ter" <-> "dbm_adapter"

Comment: corrected it, but its not any typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem declaring a type for the parameter!